# Why there is no EMF induced in this circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, electrical-engineering

Why there is no current flow in this circuit?[image]
On this diagram, the copper wires are long and extend far beyond the magnetic field range and they rotate with multimeter or BT transmitter, magnet is stationary, the blue arrows symbolize hypothetical currents. I don't understand why emf is zero here. I heard that the middle wire is also cut by the magnetic field lines so there is opposite current/voltage induced in the middle wire so everything cancels out, is that true?

The way I see it, the current in the middle wire should be induced perpendicularly to the wire ( - in the middle of the wire and + outside, just like in Faraday disk) so I don't understand how this could block the flow of the other currents coming from the side wires.

Comment: How is the magnetic flux through the loop of wire changing over time?

Comment: wires rotate over magnet "they rotate with multimeter or BT transmitter", just like faraday disk rotates in Faraday homopolar generator